# ROS Answers SE migration: URDF in Python

Tags: ros, python, urdf, robot-model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone written a class that does URDF parsing/output in Python yet? I'm debating putting one together, but don't want to replicate work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10186/urdf-in-python/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-06-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of any Python URDF parser implementation. It would be a great addition though! The full xml URDF spec is described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML).

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3